# Stripe API update account through API

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So after I create a users I need to update a users account and I use to be able to do the following:

```
$acc_details = \Stripe\Account::retrieve('');
$acc_details->legal_entity['first_name'] = 'First Name';
$acc_details.save();
```

But now for some reason it can't find legal_entity anymore, I looked at the response code and it shows it is now under individual, so I changed it, but that gives me an error of:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property Stripe\Account::$individual has no effect in update.php on line 110 (which is $acc_details->individual['first_name'] = 'First Name';)
```

Am I misreading how to update this now or is my code wrong? It has been working for the last year without any errors until this month.

Comment: Apparently, The legal_entity property on the Account API resource has been replaced with `individual`, `company`, and `business_type`. Have you tried `company`, and `business_type` as well?

Comment: @jibsteroos I have tried `individual` & `company` as the `business_type` but neither of them will update the account info using my code above. I can't seem to figure out what the issue would be at all, I have emailed stripe to see but it could be 48 hours before a response.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an official way to do this, but it seems to work for me (if stripe ever responds I will post their answer as well). When I was creating the account I had to add at least add something in the `individual` section. I am sure you could just add it all when you create the account as well. Here is my final code that is working for me:

```
$user = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
        "type" => "custom",
        "country" => "US",
        "email" => $email,
        "business_type" => "individual",
        "individual" => [
        'first_name' => $firstName, 
        'last_name' => $lastName
        ],
      ));

$token_id = $user->id;
$acct = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($token_id);

$acct->individual->dob->month = $dob_month;
$acct->individual->dob->day = $dob_day;
$acct->individual->dob->year = $dob_year;
$acct->save();
```